# Problem in mixing Java configuration with Python configuration in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Previously, I have a Google App Engine application (*jstock-static*), which is only used to host some static files so far. Inside folder WEB-INF, here are the content

**war/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

**war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>jstock-static</application>
    <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Now, I would like to host some python scripts. Instead of creating another application, I decide to make the scripts re-inside jstock-static application.

I add 2 new files to see whether it works. (They are highlighted in red)

[image]

Here is the content of newly added files.

**war/app.yaml**

```
application: jstock-static
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

I then try to upload it to app engine server using the following command.

> C:\Projects\jstock-static\war>c:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2\bin\appcfg.cmd
>   update .

However, when I make a request through web browser using http://jstock-static.appspot.com/helloworld.py, the script is not being executed. Instead, the entire python script was being downloaded.

May I know is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute Python code from an application running on the Java runtime (unless you use Jython). Python applications don't go inside a war, and need to be deployed using the appcfg.py script in the Python SDK.

Comment: But it seems like is something can be done. http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#pythonandjava Running both Python and Java in the same application?

Comment: You need to have a completely separate version of your application that uses the Python runtime, with a different version number, and deployed separately. They will not be available at the same hostname; non-default ones need to be accessed at version.latest.yourapp.appspot.com